# Creating a revision number from date/time

Tags: c#, revision

Is there an alternative to a revision number (incremented int)? I'd like to create a revision tag (or identifier if you like) from date+time (and later convert the tag back to a date time object).

Preferably the revision is as small as possible. CouchDB uses a format like this for revision: 765B7D1C - but I'm uncertain how they made this and if it's even a time stamp.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).Days
```

This returns the number of days since 2000-01-01 (as of today, this would be 3566).

This is similar to what is used in .NET if you specify the assembly version (in AssemblyInfo.cs) as "1.0.*". Of course you could also use another start date, such as the start of your project.

Comment: Well lets say there is two updates in one day... then it wouldn't work.

Comment: Wouldn't this just mean that the revId <--> revision mapping isn't necessarily bijective?  And, technically speaking, this is just a monotonically increasing integer (something OP said they wanted an alternative to) which happens to correspond to time since an arbitrary date.

Comment: The idea is good though. ((long)DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds).ToString("X") would give a result like 47C0FAF85B - better, but still needs improving

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through the same thought process.  I couldn't find a good way to fit it into the signed int that your allowed.  Instead I went with Maj.{Year-2000}.{MMdd}.{svn revision}.  You could still try and cram the date... here is the issue:

1 year = 365 days = 8760 hours = 525600 minutes.  As you can see given a max of 32k the best you can do for the current year is hours.  That can record the next 3.5 years worth, so you could do:

```
int revision = (int) (DateTime.Now - new DateTime(2009, 1, 1)).TotalHours;
```

... and this will then blow up around Aug, 2012.  Or if you use days you be able to store apx 88 years, so you could go with Martin's suggestion safely.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [VSVersion Manager](http://www.gyrum.com/Projects/VSVersion.aspx) which is a set of macros for setting version numbers in AssemblyInfo based on date.

The macro is fired on each build.

You can set up a rules for setting revision fields to any of the date elements (month, day, year in different formats), have them increment by one or leave them untouched.

The site includes detailed instructions for installing the macros.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is: Can you get the **date+time of compilation** *compiled into* your program? Preferably in the format you choose, but *any* format is sufficient, because you can re-format into a "tag" any way you like. (If you cannot re-format it at compile time, you can re-format it beyond recognition at run-time.)

The answer is: There is no *direct* way. C# has nothing like `__DATE__` or `__TIME__`. The date+time of compilation are *completely unavailable* at compile-time. If a program wants to know the date+time of its compilation, it can only *try* to pick them up at run-time, *by examining itself*. C# creates data structure(s) in and around the compiled program, but none of the fields is available at compile-time, and none is guaranteed to have the date+time of compilation.

Solution 1 (my favorite so far): VS doesn't unconditionally write the compilation date+time into suitably named fields, for the purpose of giving you that information. But it does conditionally write a derivative of the compilation date+time into 2 of the 4 version fields, as a klugey way of putting an automatic incrementing version number on the executable file, if you tell  it to. "AssemblyVersion" is a structure of 4 fields ("Major Version", "Minor Version", "Build Number", and "Revision"), which are normally just 4 UInt16 numbers typed in by the programmer (or version control software). But, **If** you set the fields of AssemblyVersion to `a`, `b`, `*`, and [empty string], **and no one changes the last 2**, then the compiler overrides the last two to `c` and `d`, where c == days and d*2 == seconds since Jan. 1, 2000 at 00:00 (local time, but disregarding daylight saving time) (making a non-human-decodable timestamp, which is visible under File Properties of the file), at the moment it parses AssemblyInfo.cs. These are easily accessed via:

```
private string DateCompiled()
{
    System.Version v = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    // v.Build == days and v.Revision*2 == seconds since Jan. 1, 2000 at 00:00 (midnight, 12:00am). (Local time, but disregards daylight saving time.)
    return new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).AddDays(v.Build).AddSeconds(v.Revision * 2).ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmm (local no DST)");

    // "Assembly version" has four UInt16 fields: "Major Version", "Minor Version", "Build Number", and "Revision".
    // When Build is "*" and Revision is empty, the compiler overrides them with the encoded date and time.
    // AssemblyVersion can be specified in the solution Properties window, Application tab, "Assembly Information..." button and dialog box: Assembly version.
    // AssemblyVersion can also be specified in "AssemblyInfo.cs". Example:
    //   [assembly: AssemblyVersion("2016.11.*")]
    // AssemblyFileVersion is optional, defaulting to AssemblyVersion if not specified. (Build is NOT allowed to be "*".)
    // Properties of the file (in Windows Explorer) displays AssemblyFileVersion.
    // AssemblyVersion can be specified in the solution Properties window, Application tab, "Assembly Information..." button and dialog box: File version.
    // AssemblyVersion can also be specified in "AssemblyInfo.cs". Example:
    //   [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.4")]
}
```

If you want File:Properties (in Internet Explorer) to show an arbitrary a.b.c.d version of your choice, you can do that too. File:Properties shows AssemblyFileVersion, which defaults to AssemblyVersion if not specified. You can only specify AssemblyFileVersion in "AssemblyInfo.cs" (just add a new line for it, using the same syntax as AssemblyVersion, except "*" is not allowed). The use of [half of] AssemblyVersion for the encoded date+time of compilation is hidden from that view.

Solution 2: (I don't like it because metadata changes easily and access could be blocked.) The running program finds itself (the .exe file) through the file system and reads its own last-modified date. But the last-modified date is metadata stored in the file system, not the program file. The last-modified date can easily be changed or lost by transfer across time-zones or DST changes via FAT, CDFS, or FTP; lazy FTP servers that do not accept incoming date+time metadata; insane FTP servers that *round* older timestamps; and file utilities that change metadata on request. And sometimes file permissions get in the way. And the needed procedure varies by operating system. (Even if I had tried this approach, I wouldn't paste code)

Solution 3: (I find it better than Solution 2 because the data cannot change, but worse than Solution 2 because the executable file *opens and reads itself* as binary data.) "Dustin Aleksiuk recently posted a clever blog entry describing how to retrieve the embedded linker timestamp from the IMAGE_FILE_HEADER section of the Portable Executable header" --https://blog.codinghorror.com/determining-build-date-the-hard-way/ (with code). The blog entry (from March 3, 2005) that it cites is gone (along with the entire blog), but it is archived at http://web.archive.org/web/20060615040705/http://blog.signaleleven.com/index.php?itemid=10

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about formatting a date, the answers vary according to the data type, the precision (resolution) that you want, the time span that you want to cover, how human-readable or machine-readable it should be and how to address time zone.

Imagine the date and time are `2016-11-08 14:08:12`. That is already a string encoding of 19 characters (19 bytes if string, not wstring).

String: I like yyyyMMdd-HHmmss: `20161108-140812`. 15 characters. I think it is *more* human readable without the dashes and colons.

BCD: Int64 stores 16 decimal digits in only 8 bytes, preserving human readability (if viewed as hexadecimal). Choices:
`0x0020161108140812` (years 0-799,999; resolution 1s)
`0x0201611081408120` (years 0-79,999; resolution 0.1s)
`0x2016110814081200` (years 0-7999; resolution 0.01s)
(First digit is limited to 0..7 because Int64 is signed; its maximum value is 0x7fffffffffffffff.)

Decimal: Int64 stores 18.96 decimal digits in only 8 bytes.
`0000020161108140812` (years 0-922,337,203; resolution 1s)
`0020161108140812000` (years 0-922,337; resolution 0.001s)
(maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.)

UInt32 can store the date (8 digits) as BCD or decimal.
`0x20161108` (years 0-9999 or 15,999)
`0020161108` (years 0-429,496)

Int32 can store the date as BCD or decimal.
`0x20161108` (years 0-7999)
`0020161108` (years 0-214,748)

There are nearly endless possibilities (if you don't look to a standard).

These are just some of the more human-readable variations.