# How to Change AssemblyInfo.cs AssemblyVersion with date/time and increment revision daily by one in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-assembly, versioning

After dig and search. I find that `AssemblyVersion` only accept `System.Int16` That mean it can't exceed 65,535 value.

the output *.DLL assembly version style I need (YYYY.M.D.HHMMSS)  **(2022.02.20.060920)**

Actually the second part first zero will omit **060920** It will be 60920, What if hour is 15 = 3 PM, It should be **150920** = 6 digits. It will not work. I guess there's a way DateTime.Now.Ticks but it gave a `System.Int64` and will never works for **Version**.

So please is there any 5 digit **hour/minute/second** style that maybe can used here? Or maybe special 5 digit Tick that have meaning.

The main problem that when I use Visual Studio auto-increment Revision 1.0.0.* feature. It gives arbitrary increment value. And the package output are not ordered.

[image: DLLs]

What should I do now? For now I need to use Time for revision field... Can you help on that please?

**Edit,** If 5 digit style not avaiable for above. I found article increment revision by one. But its very very old and use JavaScript!  https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/161923/Incrementing-AssemblyVersion-revision-number-on-ea

There's also question not answered which still new  [I would like to increment the build revision version for every build in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64817565/i-would-like-to-increment-the-build-revision-version-for-every-build-in-visual-s)

I got following code which get Version **2022.02.20.Revision** (Revision are useless during its restricted to large value midnight * 2 from MSDN.

**Edit:**
During the only [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrecisionInfinity.AutomaticVersions) in VS marketplace that do that is not updated to Visual Studio 2022 or maybe they will not supported it, I try to give solution below:

**(Feel free to modify Answer if you have better approach)**

Comment: How is the package output not ordered?  The file names are in descending order, and the time column is (or appears to be) in descending order.

Comment: Yes its ordered, But its meaningless revision number. is there any 5 digit hour/minute/second style that maybe can used please. Or how to make it increment daily? For example Day 20 Revision start from 1,2,3,4, etc.     Day 21 start from 1,2,3..

Comment: There are 86,400 seconds in a day, so you could use those 5 digits to store the time as seconds-from-midnight.  I don't think the resulting number would be any more opaque than however else you might encode a 6-digit number into 5 digits.  Also, are you really expecting to create multiple builds in the same minute?  Perhaps you could store it as `seconds / 10` or `seconds / 12`.  Closely related: [How to use release date as assembly version for a .net project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35325127/150605), [Creating a revision number from date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527596/150605)

Answer (score 10):

I was wish they update [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrecisionInfinity.AutomaticVersions) in VS marketplace.

But anyway here's solution for generate a Version with (Year, Month, Day, Incremental Daily)

**This code must inserted before close of `</project>` tag in `*.csproj` file**

```xml
<!-- Change AssemblyInfo.cs AssemblyVersion with date/time and increment revision daily by one in Visual Studio 2022 -->
<Target Name="AssemblyVersion" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" DependsOnTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Define Constants -->
        <AssemblyInfo>Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs</AssemblyInfo>
        <AssemblyInfoContent>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($(AssemblyInfo)))</AssemblyInfoContent>
        <VersionRegex>(\[\s*assembly\s*:\s*AssemblyVersion\(\s*"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.)(\d+)("\)\s*\]))</VersionRegex>
        <BuildAndRevisionRegex>(\d+\.\d+")</BuildAndRevisionRegex>

        <!-- Parse Build and Revision from AssemblyInfo-->
        <AssemblyVersion>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match('$(AssemblyInfoContent)', '$(VersionRegex)'))</AssemblyVersion>
        <BuildAndRevision>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match('$(AssemblyVersion)', '$(BuildAndRevisionRegex)'))</BuildAndRevision>
        <BuildAndRevision>$(BuildAndRevision.Remove($(BuildAndRevision.LastIndexOf('"')), 1))</BuildAndRevision>
        
        <!-- Generate Build and Revision from AssemblyVersion -->
        <Build>$(BuildAndRevision.SubString(0, $(BuildAndRevision.LastIndexOf('.'))))</Build>
        <Revision>$(BuildAndRevision.SubString($([MSBuild]::Add($(BuildAndRevision.LastIndexOf('.')), 1))))</Revision>
        
        <!-- Increment Revision by one if Build equal Current Day otherwise start from one as new Day Build-->
        <Revision Condition ="$([System.DateTime]::Now.Day) == $(Build)">$([MSBuild]::Add($(Revision), 1))</Revision>
        <Revision Condition ="$([System.DateTime]::Now.Day) != $(Build)">1</Revision>

        <!-- New AssemblyVersion Block -->
        <AssemblyVersion>[assembly: AssemblyVersion("$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy.M.d.$(Revision)"))")]</AssemblyVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Write New AssemblyVersion Block to AssemblyInfo.cs file -->
    <WriteLinesToFile File="$(AssemblyInfo)" Lines="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($(AssemblyInfoContent), $(VersionRegex), $(AssemblyVersion)))" Overwrite="true" />
</Target>
```

**A generated result will be like that:**

1. Each day a library/project will start from (Year, Month, Day, Daily Day Incremental)

[image: Incremental daily]

2. Next Day increment from one again:
   [image: Next Day increment from one again]

Comment: For .Net Core see also https://scottdorman.blog/2018/08/20/net-core-project-versioning/

Comment: nickgreek 
How can do this in VB.NET in AssemblyInfo.vb

Comment: Very clean, thank you! BTW, for anyone wanting to use this for a WPF project, as defined above this target will be called twice (making it so the Revision skips more than 1). Apparently WPF turns one project into two, as evidenced by an output build step such as the following: ```3>Done building project "Project_oktwbumw_wpftmp.csproj".``` A simple workaround is to add the following condition to the target above, as described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/issues/1009#issuecomment-1827934179): ```Condition="$(MSBuildProjectName.EndsWith('_wpftmp'))"```